# Rolling back transactions on checked and unchecked exceptions

Tags: spring, postgresql, jdbctemplate, spring-jdbc

I'm using Spring JDBC Template along with PostgreSQL. Below is my configuration
Datasource and Transaction Settings:

```
<bean id="databasePropertyConfigurer"
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
          p:location="/WEB-INF/config/database.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
          p:driverClassName="${database.driverClassName}"
          p:url="${database.url}"
          p:username="${database.username}"
          p:password="${database.password}" />

    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />
```

In my business layer, I"m doing the following:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)
@RequiresPermissions("hc:patient_createInvoice")
public Long createInvoice(Invoice invoice, List<InvoiceItem> items) throws ValidationException, NetAmountMismatchException, PatientInvoiceException
{
       try{
            dao1.insert(invoice);
       }
       catch(DataAccessException x){
            throw new PatientInvoiceException(x);
       }

       try{
            somevalidation(invoiceItem);    // Causes validation exception
            dao2.insert(invoiceItems);
       }
       catch(DataAccessException x){
       throw new PatientInvoiceException(x);
   }
}
```

Something like that. What I need is, whenever, any exception (checked or unchecked) is thrown out of this method, all the db updates performed so far should be rolled.

This is not happening with the current code.

What am I missing actually?

Answer (score 4):

By default, Spring only roll back transactions for *unchecked* exceptions. From the [Spring reference manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-rolling-back):

> Spring Framework's transaction infrastructure code only marks a transaction for rollback in the case of runtime, unchecked exceptions; [...] Checked exceptions that are thrown from a transactional method do not result in rollback in the default configuration.

However, you can configure Spring to rollback for checked exceptions as well, e.g.:

```
<tx:advice id="txAdvice">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="*" rollback-for="ValidationException, NetAmountMismatchException, PatientInvoiceException" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
```

Comment: Apologies, a bit late to respond. In this case, what exactly the use of @Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class) ? My understanding was that if I give rollbackFor=Exception.class, Exception and subclasses will be candidate for roll backs.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. You are correct, `rollbackFor` is essentially the annotated equivalence of the `rollback-for` that I used in my XML declaration, see the [reference docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-attransactional-settings) for details.

Comment: Exactly. But,using the above mentioned code, the transaction didn't roll back. it's committed to the database partially. All the exception classes mentioned above was derived from RuntimeException. Any idea? Do I still need to do the AOP stuff ?